# I have a 2012 Chevrolet Camaro 2lt with a lot of problems

Tags: chevrolet, misfire, cylinder, electronic-stability-control

I have a 2012 Chevrolet Camaro RS and I'm getting a cylinder 6 misfire. I swapped the spark plugs because they were burnt, but I'm still getting a cylinder 6 misfire. I even checked the coil packs. They're not bad, but I see I have a lot of carbon deposits and I want to clean that out. When I turn the car on, it idles fine for a few until I get a service StabiliTrak message. Then, it starts to idle rough until it cuts off by itself.

What should I do?

Comment: You say that you checked the coils. Did you try swapping the #6 coil with another cylinder? How did you test the coil?

Answer (score 0):

A compression or leak down test. Check fuel injector on #6. It should click rapidly when running. Use a very long screwdriver. One end on injector, the other end on ear. Or use stethoscope.

Comment: How would I check the injector

Comment: Use a stethoscope or take a very long screwdriver and put one end of the screwdriver on the injector and your ear on the other end. You should hear a rapid clicking when engine is running. Be careful to stay away from fan and moving pulleys.